# Query entire file but by separate data, grouped by each unique column element

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

Given a data set similar to:

```
╔═════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ FIELD1  ║ FIELD2 ║ FIELD3 ║
╠═════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 11-1.01 ║ Jacob  ║      3 ║
║ 11-1.02 ║ Jacob  ║      4 ║
║ 12-2.01 ║ Jacob  ║      3 ║
║ 13-3.01 ║ Jacob  ║      4 ║
║ 13-3.02 ║ Jacob  ║      3 ║
║ 13-3.03 ║ Jacob  ║      2 ║
║ 11-1.01 ║ Chris  ║      3 ║
║ 11-1.02 ║ Chris  ║      4 ║
║ 12-2.01 ║ Chris  ║      2 ║
║ 13-3.01 ║ Chris  ║      4 ║
║ 13-3.02 ║ Chris  ║      3 ║
║ 13-3.03 ║ Chris  ║      2 ║
║ 11-1.01 ║ Mike   ║      4 ║
║ 11-1.02 ║ Mike   ║      3 ║
╚═════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

I need to find the average of the Field3 values for the repeating pre-decimal values of Field1 (the after decimal values are not important), for each unique Field2 element. 
Field1 values are defined as type CHAR and 7 digits in length (including hyphen and decimal).

I am currently able to find the averages for one specific Field2 element by using a WHERE clause, as such:

```
SELECT prefix, COUNT(prefix), Field2, FORMAT(AVG(suffix),2)
FROM
(
  SELECT LEFT(Field1,4) AS prefix, Field3 AS suffix, Field2
  FROM mytable WHERE Field2 = 'Jacob'
)x
GROUP BY prefix;
```

However, it is my goal to run through the entire file and find averages for each different Field2 element, so I don't need to run the program as many times as there are unique Field2 names. 
I feel like this should be a rather easy change to my current code but have no idea what to do.
There is probably a better way to structure this data in a table, although this is how I've received it and must work with it (I don't know much about it).

**UPDATE 1**

Desired Result

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ PREFIX ║ PREFIXCOUNT ║ FIELD2 ║ AVERAGE ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 11-1   ║           2 ║ Chris  ║ 3.50    ║
║ 12-2   ║           1 ║ Chris  ║ 2.00    ║
║ 13-3   ║           3 ║ Chris  ║ 3.00    ║
║ 11-1   ║           2 ║ Jacob  ║ 3.50    ║
║ 12-2   ║           1 ║ Jacob  ║ 3.00    ║
║ 13-3   ║           3 ║ Jacob  ║ 3.00    ║
║ 11-1   ║           2 ║ Mike   ║ 3.50    ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: what is you desired result then based on the example above?

Comment: Hi JW, 
My desired result would be something similar to the following:

   `prefix    COUNT(prefix)    Field2    AVG(suffix)`
   `11-1      2                Jacob     3.5`
   `12-2      1                Jacob     3`
   `13-3      3                Jacob     3`
   `11-1      2                Chris     3.5`
   `12-2      1                Chris     2`
   `13-3      3                Chris     3`
   `11-1      2                Mike      3.5`
    (And so on for every other Field2 name in the file)`


Thank you for your quick response.
Edit* My code isn't working in comments. Trying to sort that out.

Comment: how about the answer below? `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `where` clause on the subquery and grouped them by `prefix` and `Field2`.

```
SELECT  prefix, 
        COUNT(prefix) PrefixCount, 
        Field2, 
        FORMAT(AVG(suffix),2) Average
FROM
        (
          SELECT    LEFT(Field1,4) AS prefix, 
                    Field3 AS suffix, 
                    Field2
          FROM      TableName 
        )   x
GROUP   BY prefix, Field2
ORDER   BY Field2, prefix
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92685/12)

The output,

```
+--------+-------------+--------+---------+
| PREFIX | PREFIXCOUNT | FIELD2 | AVERAGE |
+--------+-------------+--------+---------+
| 11-1   |           2 | Chris  | 3.50    |
| 12-2   |           1 | Chris  | 2.00    |
| 13-3   |           3 | Chris  | 3.00    |
| 11-1   |           2 | Jacob  | 3.50    |
| 12-2   |           1 | Jacob  | 3.00    |
| 13-3   |           3 | Jacob  | 3.00    |
| 11-1   |           2 | Mike   | 3.50    |
+--------+-------------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Perfect, produces exactly what I'm looking for. 
Thanks a lot JW, very relieving to have this!